# Histogram with small numbers shows just a line

Tags: histogram

I want to implement a histogram. My code worked for the time I've used numbers between 0 and 10, but with my new numbers it just shows me a line and no histogramm.

Can someone give me advice to fix this?

Writing the numbers without division?

````
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
xticklabel=
\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
]
\addplot+ [hist={bins=3}]
table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
$6/94$\\ $4/94$\\ $8/94$\\ $3/94$\\ $7/94$\\ $2/94$\\ $2/94$\\ $5/94$\\ $1/94$\\ $1/94$\\ $1/94$\\ $9/94$\\
$6/94$\\ $4/94$\\ $10/94$\\ $3/94$\\ $3/94$\\ $5/94$\\ $2/94$\\ 0\\ $1/94$\\ $4/94$\\ $1/94$\\ $2/94$\\ $4/94$\\
};%Was diese Strich lan
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the fractions (but need to remove the `$` signs) with `y expr=\thisrow{data}`. Whether or not this is precisely the output you are after, I do not know.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
xticklabel=
\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
xticklabel style={yshift={-(1+pow(-1,1+\ticknum))*0.6em}}
]
\addplot+ [hist={bins=3}]
table [row sep=\\,y expr=\thisrow{data}] {
data\\
6/94\\ 4/94\\ 8/94\\ 3/94\\ 7/94\\ 2/94\\ 2/94\\ 5/94\\ 1/94\\ 1/94\\ 1/94\\ 9/94\\
6/94\\ 4/94\\ 10/94\\ 3/94\\ 3/94\\ 5/94\\ 2/94\\ 0\\ 1/94\\ 4/94\\ 1/94\\ 2/94\\ 4/94\\
};%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]